# AVAudioSession Interruption notification fires only once

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, avaudiosession

In my iOS app I'm registering to the AVAudioSession Interruption notifications like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleAudioSessionInterruption:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:nil];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

When I test my app by playing some random music from youtube, handleAudioSessionInterruption method fires for the first time (InterruptionBegan). When I quit youtube app, the method gets fired again (InterruptionEnded). Now I repeat the same steps as before and method does not get fired at all and I need to restart my app to make it work again. Can someone tell what could be wrong or point to some sample implementation.

Note : I neither see any errors nor the app crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the observer is getting removed from `NSNotificationCenter`. Make sure that that is not happening. Calling `removeObserver:self` without specifying a notification name will remove self from `NSNotificationCenter` for ALL notifications.

Also try making `AppDelegate` an observer of `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification` in addition to the observer that you are currently registering. If the `AppDelegate`'s handler keeps getting called even after your other handler stops getting called then that will give you more information.